# Trying to make a program in Python that plays a note based on user input. But whenever I input a single note, it plays them all in order. Why?

Tags: python

```
from playsound import playsound
notes = input("What would you like to play?:\n").split(", ")


for c in notes:
    if "a" or "A" in notes:
        playsound('/Users/Keller/Downloads/mp3 Notes/a5.mp3')
    else:
        pass
    if "b" or "B" in notes:
        playsound('/Users/Keller/Downloads/mp3 Notes/b5.mp3')
    else:
        pass
    if "c" or "C" in notes:
        playsound('/Users/Keller/Downloads/mp3 Notes/c5.mp3')
    else:
        pass
    if "d" or "D" in notes:
        playsound('/Users/Keller/Downloads/mp3 Notes/d5.mp3')
    else:
        pass
    if "e" or "E" in notes:
        playsound('/Users/Keller/Downloads/mp3 Notes/e5.mp3')
    else:
        pass
    if "f" or "F" in notes:
        playsound('/Users/Keller/Downloads/mp3 Notes/f5.mp3')
    else:
        pass
    if "g" or "G" in notes:
        playsound('/Users/Keller/Downloads/mp3 Notes/g5.mp3')
    else:
        pass
```

Please excuse the gross cluster of if statements. My intention was to fix it once I got the code up and running. I realize now this is probably part of the problem.

Comment: You should use a dictionary instead of multiple if elses and simply grep for the letter in dict keys.

Comment: What input did you pass into notes, what did it play (which notes in what order), and what did you expect it to play?

Comment: @NelsonGon Thanks for the feedback. New-ish to Python, so I appreciate it. I'll look into it.

Comment: `"a" in notes or "A" in notes`. Currently you're doing `if "a"` which is always `True`.

Comment: @M.Chak I just input a, or any other letter, and it's supposed to play only the audio file for that note. Instead, whenever I input any note it loops through and plays the audio file for every note.

Comment: As @Loocid noted, all of your conditions are always true.

Comment: A dict is honestly overkill. The only part of the filename that changes is the note, so use an f-string: `playsound(f'/Users/Keller/Downloads/mp3 Notes/{note}5.mp3')`

Comment: should be `if "a" in c or "A" in c` instead

Comment: Instead of all the `if`s, just do one line: `playsound(f'/Users/Keller/Downloads/mp3 Notes/{c.lower()}5.mp3')`.  Wrap it in a `try` to catch whatever exception it raises if there's no such file.